# asp.net authorize by default (without [Authorize])

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-5, asp.net-authorization, asp.net5

I have an asp.netcore .net 5 application.

I've got authorization working with the `[Authorize]` attribute above the controller endpoint.

How can I make it use authorization without having to use the `[Authorize]` attribute? Here is how I set up my authorization:

I have this in `ConfigureServices`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{...
        FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
        {
            Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("firebase_admin_sdk.json"),
        });

        services
        .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "https://securetoken.google.com/vepo-xxx";
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/vepo-xxx",
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = "vepo-xxx",
                ValidateLifetime = true
            };
        });
...}
```

And in I `Configure` have:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, VepoContext context, ISearchIndexService searchIndexService)
{...
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
...}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the docs for [Require authenticated users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-5.0#require-authenticated-users). You can add a `RequireAuthenticatedUser()` to all controllers:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    ...

    services.AddControllers(config =>
    {
        // using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
        // using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                         .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                         .Build();
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });
```